# Llamar procedimiento almacenado en SAP HANA desde SQL Server a través de Servidor vinculado

Tags: sql, sap, hana

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un procedimiento que tengo almacenado en SAP_ HANA y me sale el siguiente error:

SQL query:

```
Exec HANASERVER.."VILLANUEVA_FINAL"."VNSA_SALDOP" 'C00000007'
```

Error:

> El proveedor OLE DB "MSDASQL" del servidor vinculado "HANASERVER" devolvió el mensaje "[SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near ";": line 1 col 41 (at pos 41)".
> Msg 7212, Level 17, State 1, Line 9
> No se pudo ejecutar el procedimiento 'VNSA_SALDOP' en el servidor remoto 'HANASERVER'.

¿Alguna solución?

Gracias.

Comment: Versión de SQL Server?

Comment: Estimado, SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2016

Comment: Hmmm, es raro porque menciona un error de sintaxis. El procedimiento retorna algo (y no se lo estás asignando a una variable)? El usuario con el que llegas a HANASERVER a través del linkedServer, tiene permisos para ejecutar ese SP?

Comment: Si, en HANA se me ejecuta perfecto, nose si tendra algo que ver el OLE DB "MSDASQL"  que no reconozca procedimientos

Comment: Si vas al Object Explorer, clic derecho en el linked server (HANASERVER), Test connection, te dice que funciona? Si es así, no debería ser el ODBC.

Comment: Sisi funciona, lo uso para vistas y consultar tablas.. me anda perfecto. consulta usas HANA?

Comment: por favor intente así. EXEC ('call schema_name.sp_name (''p1 value'',''p2 value'')') AT hana_linked_server_name